# Changing images onclick

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want the image to change when someone clicks on it, but this isn't working.

```
<image id="s" src="s.jpg" onclick="reaction()" ></image>
    function reaction()
    {
    var replace=document.getElementById("s").src;
    replace="20141018_222702.jpg";
    }
```

Can someone explain me the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you use retrieved the value of `src` and placed it in a variable called `replace` like so:

```
var replace=document.getElementById("s").src;
```

After that you changed the content of the `variable` like so:

```
replace="20141018_222702.jpg";
```

All a variable does is hold a value. You just changed the value/content that the variable holds, which results in nothing happening.

What you should do is have the variable hold the element itself, like so:

```
var replace=document.getElementById("s");
```

Then have javascript change the `src` property/attribute of the element it holds, like so:

```
replace.src="20141018_222702.jpg";
```

I hope this clears out your doubts :)

Comment: Okay.I got it.
And does innerHTML refer to the actual element in the tag?

Comment: No, `innerHTML` will just give you the text that is between opening and closing tags. Putting that in a variable and changing it will result in nothing, just like it happened for the image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out!